# Better way to convert an NSArray of NSStrings to NSNumbers

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Consider the following code

```
NSString *param_string @"1:3:6:10:15:22:28:30";
NSArray *params = [param_string componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];

NSMutableArray *convertedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[params count]];

for(int i = 0; i < [params count]; i++){
    [convertedArray insertObject:[formatter numberFromString:[params objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:i]];
}
```

Is there a better, more efficient way of achieving this? The initial param_string could be longer in practice but I don't expect there to ever be more than approximately 200 elements in the params array.

Thanks

Comment: does the order of elements must be the same in the input string and in the array?

Comment: not necessarily, if the order of the elements gets rearranged it wont matter ultimately

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this.

Add a category to NSString

```
@interface NSString(MyConverter)

-(NSDecimalNumber*) decimalNumberValue;

@end

@implementation NSString(MyConverter)

-(NSDecimalNumber*) decimalNumberValue
{
    return [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: self];
}

@end
```

Now you can do this

```
NSString *param_string @"1:3:6:10:15:22:28:30";
NSArray *params = [param_string componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

NSArray* decimalNumbers = [params valueForKey: @"decimalNumberValue"];
```

Clearly if you want some other object than a NSDecimalNumber, just alter your category accordingly.  The method just has to return an object that can be put in an array.

Comment: Thank you, I like this solution, I'm still quite a fresh obj-c programmer and wasn't aware of the valueForKey method, I think I'll be using it considerably more often now.

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` has an instance method `intValue` that might make this more straightforward.

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numerWithInt:[[params objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
```

Now insert that `value` into the array.  If the string is always this simple, you really don't  a number formatter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm using a number formatter because the numbers might eventually get big enough to overflow an int so I can't presume that intValue will work.

Comment: Well there is `doubleValue` and `longValue` methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the `NSScanner` and avoid 2 loops (one inside `componentsSeparatedByString` and one that fills your mutable array).

With `NSScanner` you may accomplish your goal with one while and only one array (mutable array of numbers).