# how to convert NSString to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have a string like

```
NSString* str = @"[90, 5, 6]";
```

I need to convert it to an array like

```
NSArray * numbers = [90, 5 , 6];
```

I did a quite long way like this:

```
+ (NSArray*) stringToArray:(NSString*)str
{
    NSString *sep = @"[,";
    NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:sep];
    NSArray *temp=[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:set];

    NSMutableArray* numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString* s in temp) {
        NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[s integerValue]];
        [numbers addObject:n];
    }

    return numbers;
}
```

Is there any neat and quick way to do such conversion?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First remove the unwanted characters from the string, like white spaces and braces:

```
NSString* str = @"[90, 5, 6]";
NSCharacterSet* characterSet = [[NSCharacterSet
                                 characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789,"] invertedSet];
NSString* newString = [[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet]
                       componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

You will have a string like this: `90,5,6`. Then simply split using the comma and convert to `NSNumber`:

```
NSArray* arrayOfStrings = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSMutableArray* arrayOfNumbers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:arrayOfStrings.count];
for (NSString* string in arrayOfStrings) {
    [arrayOfNumbers addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:string]];
}
```

Using the `NSString` category from [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3430555/469218) it can be simplified to:

```
NSArray* arrayOfStrings = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSArray* arrayOfNumbers = [arrayOfStrings valueForKey: @"decimalNumberValue"];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
NSString* str = @"[90, 5, 6]";
NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[] "];
NSArray *array = [[[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet]
                        componentsJoinedByString:@""]     
                        componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Comment: why don't you just _sepatatedByString_ with `@", "`? anyway (+1) because that could be the most light-hearted and working solution.

Comment: @holex Yeah, we can add `whitespace` with `NSCharacterSet` as i edited `@"[] "` will be good and thanks a lot for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
NSArray *arr = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Comment: but I still have "[", and another thing is the returned array contains NSString elements instead of NSInteger elements

Comment: `[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];`
`[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[]"]];` ;)

Comment: @chipbk10 use like this                                        NSArray *Arr = [Str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

[Arr objectAtIndex:0];//90
[Arr objectAtIndex:1];//5
[Arr objectAtIndex:2];//6

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *newSTR = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[" withString:@""];

newSTR = [newSTR stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"]" withString:@""];

NSArray *items = [newSTR componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using regular expression

([0-9]+)

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSString* str = @"[90, 5, 6]";
NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([0-9]+)" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
```

Then you have a NSArray of string, you just need to iterate it and convert the strings to number and insert them into an array.