# How to convert NSString to NSArray in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring, nsarray

I need to convert NSString to NSArray. if, few objects contains double quotes, few objects are doesn't contain anything.

```
NSString *string = @"["Line", "Operations(UK)", "Operations(USA)", "Total of Invoice", "", "Star", "10040101", "31.Jan.2001", "31.Jan.2001", "", "USD", "1653", "28,145.00", 163.48, "Stock, Ms.Pat", "MGR", "14.Nov.2006", "01-000-2210-0000-000", "V1- New York City", 20343, 5]"; 
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:&e];
```

I have tried to convert using replacing characters like [, ", ] and did "componentsSeparatedByString:" with comma. but its not working properly.

Comment: It seems like you didn't escape the quotes in your string literal. Use backslashes before the quotes (`\"`) to escape them.

Comment: may b this will help you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/25502212/5085393

Answer (score 1):

As i see, you are doing right way to convert from `NSString` to `NSArray`. When you declare a `NSString`, you have to use `\"` instead of `"`. It works with me.

```
NSString *string = @"[\"Line\", \"Operations(UK)\", \"Operations(USA)\", \"Total of Invoice\", \"\", \"Star\", \"10040101\", \"31.Jan.2001\", \"31.Jan.2001\", \"\", \"USD\", \"1653\", \"28,145.00\", 163.48, \"Stock, Ms.Pat\", \"MGR\", \"14.Nov.2006\", \"01-000-2210-0000-000\", \"V1- New York City\", 20343, 5]";
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you solution with example.I tried this.I got the solution.

```
NSString *strJson=@"{\"name\":{\"dob\":88,\"age\":61},\"family\" : [{\"location\":\"us\",\"mobile\":\"mobile\"}]}";
NSData *data = [strJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",dict);
```

The output result is

[image]